# How to get values from dropdownlist, radiolist and checkbox list

Tags: php, web, yii2

Helli i have simple form, which inserting data in my table, the problem is that i don't know how to:
1)get String value of selected dropdownlist item;
2)get String value of selected radio element
3)get smthng like String arrray of selected checkboxes;
Here is the form

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'first_name') ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'last_name') ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'gender')->radioList([
            1 => 'Male',
            2 => 'Female'
        ]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'faculty')->dropdownList([
            1 => 'Faculty of Information Technology',
            2 => 'Faculty of Math Science',
            3 => 'Faculty of Ukrainian Literature',
            4 => 'Faculty of Health'
        ]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'languages')->checkboxList([
            1 => 'Java',
            2 => 'C++',
            3 => 'C#',
            4 => 'Python',
            5 => 'PHP',
            6 => 'Java Script'
        ]) ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

ActiveRecord class

```
class Users extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'users';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'faculty', 'languages'], 'required'],
            [['first_name', 'last_name'], 'string', 'max' => 15],
            [['gender'], 'string', 'max' => 7],
            [['faculty'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
            [['languages'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'first_name' => 'First Name',
            'last_name' => 'Last Name',
            'gender' => 'Gender',
            'faculty' => 'Faculty',
            'languages' => 'Programming Languages',
        ];
    }

    public static function primaryKey()
    {
        return ['customer_id','group_id'];
    }
}
```

So problem is that values that inserted in db after form accepted is indexes of selected values, but i need values

Comment: must be able to have a structure equivalent to that use in the view .. submit only returns the index but not the associated description

Comment: Have you tried removing the indices in your form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) To get string value from dropdown list you should use strings as indexes in array, eg:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'faculty')->dropdownList([
    'Faculty of Information Technology' => 'Faculty of Information Technology',
    'Faculty of Math Science' => 'Faculty of Math Science',
    'Faculty of Ukrainian Literature' => 'Faculty of Ukrainian Literature',
    'Faculty of Health' => 'Faculty of Health'
]) ?>
```

2) In selected radio element the same way.

3) To get array of checked elements, you should create extra attribute in your ActiveRecord class:

```
public $languagesIds = [];
```

and in view use this:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'languagesIds')->checkboxList([
    1 => 'Java',
    2 => 'C++',
    3 => 'C#',
    4 => 'Python',
    5 => 'PHP',
    6 => 'Java Script'
]) ?>
```

After load model from post data, `$model->languagesIds` will filled with checked values. If you'd like to have array of strings, replace indexes (1,2,3,4..) to strings, like in point 1 and 2.

Comment: I still have problem with checkboxes, i made array in my ActiveRecord class, but when i trying to get him like $arr = $model->languagesIds, i always have an empty array

Comment: Try to add this rule `['languagesIds', 'safe'],` to rules in ActivRecord, or if it should be required - to required array rule.